# Explode array values into different columns without knowing the values beforehand

Tags: sql, presto

I am extracting data from a JSON column which results in an array of strings. I would now like to create a column for each string found, and set the resulting column to TRUE if the string is in the array of the row.

e.g.

Starting table:

```
id    values
1     ["value2", "value3"]
2     []
3     ["value1"]
4     ["value1", "value2"]
5     ["value3"]
```

Resulting table:

```
id    value1    value2    value3
1     FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
2     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
3     TRUE      FALSE     FALSE
4     TRUE      TRUE      FALSE
5     FALSE     FALSE     TRUE
```

Is it possible to do this without knowing the possible values of the strings beforehand?

Comment: I found this page dedicated to [JSON for SQL Serveur](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - you should at least tag your rdbms

Comment: This might be possible, depending on your DBMS, but not using pure SQL, you would almost certainly need to use a stored procedure. For example, you are likely to need 2 passes through the data as you wouldn’t know the column list until you had been through the data once

Comment: @NickW Edited the tags. I amusing Presto, but am sure I will be able to edit an existing solution on another DBMS.

Comment: Ok - so give it a go and ask another question if you run into a specific issue